# Dimension of a module (which is not necessarily finite)

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R=\bigoplus_{ n\in\mathbb N}R_{ n}$ be a Noetherian standard ring defined over an Artinian local ring. Let $M=\bigoplus_{ n\in\mathbb N}M_{ n}$ be an $\mathbb N$-graded $R$-module (**not necessarily finite**) with $\lambda_{R_{ 0}}(M_{ n})<\infty$ for all $n.$ Suppose there exists a polynomial $P$ such that $P(n)=\lambda_{R_{ 0}}(M_{ n})$ for all large $n.$

**Question** Can we say dim $M$=deg $P?$

Comment: No, and Remy van Dobben de Bruyn already explained the examples.  The graded $R$-module $M = \oplus_n (R/R_+)(n)^{\oplus P(n)}$ has the specified length function, but it has support equal to $R_+ = \oplus_{n>0} R_n$.  So the dimension is $0$.